# Insert 1 parent row and many child rows Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I am creating a system where you can create forms and store them in the database which will be displayed for specific types of reports.

On a report you will be entering 1 row into the Report table with the default report data like report owner, submission date, status etc

On this same create page I would like to have all of the values from the created form that's stored in the DB, so far I have managed to get the displayed form to show correctly with the report.

Each input for the form in the DB will be 1 entry into the ReportValues table.

Currently I can get the Report from the Create View but the entries for ReportValue are not being returned to the Create Iaction.

Please help :/

Models:

```
public class Report
{
    public Report()
    {
        //Set default Submission Date to the current date.
        this.SubmissionDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.Status = "New";
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Form")]
    public int formID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public String Abreviation { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Submitted By")]
    public String Owner { get; set; }


    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
    public String Category { get; set; }

    public String Status { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date), Display(Name = "Submit Date")]
    public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }

    }
}

    public class ReportValues
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Report")]
    public int reportId { get; set; }
    public String title { get; set; }
    public String value { get; set; }
}
}

    public class FormReportViewModel
{
    public Report Report { get; set; }
    public int reportID { get; set; }
    public String formCode { get; set; }
    public String abv { get; set; }
    public String category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReportValues> ReportValues { get; set; }
}
}
```

Create Iaction:

```
        // POST: Reports/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(FormReportViewModel formReportViewModel)
    {
        Report r = formReportViewModel.Report;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Report.Add(r);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var item in formReportViewModel.ReportValues)
            {
                ReportValues rv = new ReportValues { reportId = r.ID, title = item.title, value = item.value };
                _context.ReportValues.Add(rv);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(formReportViewModel);
    }
```

View:

```
model IEnumerable<FormReportViewModel>
@using System.Security.Claims;

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Report</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.First().Report.Abreviation" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="@Model.First().Report.Abreviation" class="form-control" value="@Model.First().abv" readonly="readonly"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.First().Report.Abreviation" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.First().Report.Category" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="@Model.First().Report.Category" class="form-control" value="@Model.First().category" readonly="readonly"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.First().Report.Category" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.First().Report.Owner" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="@Model.First().Report.Owner" class="form-control" value=@User.GetUserName() readonly="readonly"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.First().Report.Owner" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.First().Report.Status" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="@Model.First().Report.Status" class="form-control" value="New" readonly="readonly"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.First().Report.Status" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
       @*Html.Raw(Model.First().formCode)*@
       @*
            The code below is from the Create ReportValues page    
       *@
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="title">title</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" value="Animal Name" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="title" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="value">value</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="value" name="value" value="" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="value" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="title">title</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" value="Animal Weight" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="title" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="value">value</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="value" name="value" value="" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="value" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="title">title</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" value="Animal Colour" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="title" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="value">value</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="value" name="value" value="" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="value" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>




<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the definition of FormReportViewModel

Comment: Editted the origianl with the model requested

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the view

Comment: Added the view, for clarification, I was extracting the HTML from the DB but in the current code that is commented out and I hard coded the elements by taking the code from the actual create ReportValues page as the rendered form from the DB was not working

Comment: So the entries are returned as null? or empty?

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
ReportManagement.Controllers.ReportsController.Create(FormReportViewModel formReportViewModel) in ReportsController.cs, line 85

  Thanks for perseveering with me

Comment: Where exactly are you getting it? at the foreach line?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that error? at the foreach line?

Comment: Yes on the foreach line

Comment: Add a constructor in FormReportViewModel and create a new instance of ReportValues, I would also change IEnumerable<ReportValues> to List<ReportValues> so you cold do List<ReportValues> ReportValues=new List<ReportValues>

Answer (score 0):

From the comments: you have a NRE in FormReportViewModel, ReportValues is null.

Change `IEnumerable<ReportValues>` to `List<ReportValues>`, add a constructor in FormReportViewModel and create an instance of ReportValues

```
public class FormReportViewModel
{ 
  public Report Report { get; set; }
  public int reportID { get; set; }
  public String formCode { get; set; }
  public String abv { get; set; }
  public String category { get; set; }
  public List<ReportValues> ReportValues { get; set; }

  public FormReportViewModel()
  {
      ReportValues=new List<ReportValues>(); 
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean ReportValues = new List(ReportValues) in the constructor? its throwing an error on the "List()";

Comment: What is the error? (When asking on these QA sites you have to be very specific about everything, don't wait until someone asks you what is the error)

Comment: Sorry, you have to specify the type in list, answer updated

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I'll try and be more specific. Ok so at this point the Report is submitting fine, no errors are happening but the values in the inputs for the reportvalues fields are not being entered into the ReportValues table still.

Comment: Yeah, about that, you have IEnumerable<FormReportViewModel> model in your view but in your create action you receive a single object, also I don't understand how are you binding the ReportValues detail in your view.

Comment: Perhaps if you could simplify and reproduce the problem in dotnetfiddle I could be more helpful. https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsMvc

Comment: I feel like were probably chasing a dead end with the way I have things set up, I am really new to using asp.net and MVC, this is my first project. Is there any way you would recommend passing into 2 tables from 1 view?

Comment: You need to bind to a nested collection of models, you iterate each model and create controls in each iteration, you bind the controls to the properties of each model and when you submit you should have everything in in your main FormReportViewModel, I'll try to find a good tutorial.

Comment: I appreciate the help ATM, a tutorial to work from would be great, you are a saint :)